# Entity Framework translating number(1) to Boolean help?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, .net-3.5, devart

Im using Devart dotConnect for Oracle - Entity Framework + .NET 3.5. When i create the Entities, the framework change those colums type number(1) into bool. I read that it is a feature of every kind of entity framework. But i don't want it.. We use here number(1) to specify status of an db object.. like Clients - Situation.

I tried to set manually the .ssdl "bool" to "int" and .csdl "Boolean" to "Int32".. it just keep the same error of convert... if i use the "Run Custom Tool" it changes back the field to bool and Boolean.

I tried to change de property manually too in the Diagram.. w/o sucess.

Comment: Whats the data type in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Model explorer you will need to change the datatype of the column in the table in the ".Store" part of the model as well.   The datatype of the class.property in your xxxModel part needs to match with the datatype of the table.column in your xxxModel.Store.  If you choose Int32 in your class, you could choose Decimal in the table.

Comment: im sry dude.. what u mean with ".Store" is it the Model Explorer Windows ? where i can set the propertys manualy ?

Comment: nvm.. i find it. Seems to be it.. ill try to set everyone. anyway .. why i havent sucess setting manually in the .ssdl ?

Comment: u did it ! but let me ask u again.. can i set it somewhere ? we have more than 100 tables in each Software.. u know ? this kind of dumb work is sad.

Comment: @MalGaniS You can see it in your .edml file.  There you have one section for the class/entity (including datatypes of the columns), one section that contains mapping between the class and the table (no datatypes) and one section with the table definition (with the database datatypes)